# Python project won't run

Tags: python, pycharm

Yesterday I tried out Python, everything worked out fine. But today when I woke up and ran PyCharm, it refused to run *any* Python code. Minimal example:

Code:

```
def main():
    print("Text")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe D:/Python/TestProject/src/__init__.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the if __name__ == '__main__' , probably pycharm is treatening your code as a module or something, and try changing the name of your file to something other than init.

Comment: `print` should be indented one step to the right.

Comment: @Fredrik Pihl Thanks, that dit it, never knew python was THAT sensitive

Comment: @Aerrathas -- that is one of the many benefits with python. You are forces to have proper indented programs. Takes some time to get used to but soon it becomes 2nd nature!

Comment: So that was the problem, I wonder why python hasn't raised an exception..

Comment: @no_name -- it should throw an `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. But I never used pycharm so I can't tell

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have not configured the `Configuration\Script` in your file yet.

To do that, follow this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a module, the `__init__.py` file is executed when the module is loaded. In that module, `__name__` is the module's name. You should be able to see this with `print __name__`.

in `./mod/__init__.py:`

```
print(__name__)
```

in the interpreter:

```
>>> import mod
mod
```

So, `__name__` clearly isn't `'__main__'`, so nothing happens.

Comment: read the comments of the question, the question is already answered